# S3 | bucket_key_enabled for aws s3 sync command

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

S3 has recently announced "bucket_key_enabled" option to cache the kms key used to encrypt the bucket contents so that the number of calls to the kms server is reduced.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/bucket-key.html

Any idea how to make use of this in `aws s3 sync` command?

---

EDIT :  To be clear, my usecase is where there is no encryption configuration at bucket level. I am using options `--sse aws:kms --sse-kms-key-id $KMS_KEY_ARN` in order to encrypt the objects

Comment: If the S3 Bucket Key is present and objects are being encrypted, then the Bucket Key will be used automatically regardless of how the objects are created. Thus, you do not "use" it in the AWS CLI, aside from specifying that you would like the objects to be encrypted. Such a request is no different to the situation where a Bucket Key is _not_ being used.

Comment: Thanks John. So buckeyKeyEnabled does not make sense at the object level. Am I right? I have  a bucket with no default encryption. I am wondering if there is any use of buckeyKeyEnabled option at object level.

Comment: Bucket usage pattern in my usecase is detailed here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65291066/aws-s3-bucket-key-enabled